# Why using Activity context cause Context memory leak

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, memory-leaks, android-context

I've searched many times on Google about "use **Application Context** or **Activity Context**".

Most of the answers are: "Use application context **getApplicationContext()** as much as possible to prevent Context memory leak".

I am confused:

Why using Activity context may cause memory leak although:

"**Activity** context is associated with the activity and can be destroyed if the activity is destroyed"

BUT

"**Application** context is associated with the application and will always be same throughout the life of application -- it does not change" ?

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` instances are transient: they come and go based on user interaction with your app.  Your app overall has a single `Application` instance which exists for the lifetime of the process of your app.  Take a simple example: the user starts your app via the launcher (home screen), your `MainActivity` is created and launched.  If this was the first launch then your app's process is started an an `Application` context created as well.  The user presses the `BACK` key and your `MainActivity` is exited, going through its `onDestroy()`.  Now if the user re-launches your app, a new instance of `MainActivity` is created.  However, your app's process was not killed (assuming there was no memory pressure) so the `Application` object singleton still exists and is valid.  Your original `MainActivity` instance does not exist.

Comment: Because of my "original MainActivity" is exited, so all references/variables and then memory will be released as well?

Comment: Not necessarily, which is the root cause of the memory leak problem.  If you use your activity as the context for something which is not tied to the life cycle of your activity and then your activity is destroyed (lifecycle), the garbage collector cannot discard your `Activity` object because there is still a strong reference being held.  Have a look at this Google Android Developer blog for more details: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html